# My web scraping/searching project is not giving me the correct results

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraping / searching project with beautifulsoup, but when i run this code all i'm getting is None. Im sure i've checked the open-source html code on google with respect to the part of the web-page I want to scrape. Here's the code-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

topic_search = input('Enter your search queries: ')
search = topic_search.replace('', '+')

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + topic_search + "&start" + str(0)
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features='lxml')
result = soup.find('div', id='result-stats')

print(result)
```

But the only result getting printed is "None". I don't know what to do. Please help. Also, even if I use soup.find_all apart from soup.find, i still get "[]" as the result. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?

Firstly check if it does correctly get page source, add

```
print(response)
```

immediately after

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=header).text
```

run that, does it print intended source of page? If not fix that, if that works well then

```
soup.find('div', id='result-stats')
```

giving `None` means that there is not element fullfilling these criteria. You need to alter arguments to describe *existing* element. Notice that `id` if used should be unique, so if you want to access element with given `id` you should be able to do that providing id alone.

Comment: Yeah the response is good. but i do not get what u mean be unique id @Daweo

Comment: @PranavKannambadi in other words, there must not be 2 or more different elements with same `id` in given page